# how to download image from any web page in java

Tags: java, html, download

hi
  I am trying to download image from web page.
  I am trying to download the image from 'http://www.yahoo.com' home page.
  Please tell me how to pass 'http://www.yahoo.com' as a input.
  And on opening this web page how to fetch image from this page.
  Please give me java code to fetch the image from web page.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

```
try (URL url = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/image_to_read.jpg")) {
    Image image = ImageIO.read(url);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle IOException
}
```

See `javax.imageio` package for more info.  That's using the AWT image.  Otherwise you could do:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/image_to_read.jpg");
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int n = 0;
while (-1!=(n=in.read(buf)))
{
   out.write(buf, 0, n);
}
out.close();
in.close();
byte[] response = out.toByteArray();
```

And you may then want to save the image so do:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C://borrowed_image.jpg");
fos.write(response);
fos.close();
```

Comment: For Java7 modify the code snippet to use the try-with-resources statement, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: Just a thought, as I had trouble saving the file using standard InputStreamReader wrapped under FileInputStream for the remote URL. I got the file, but it wasn't valid. Why so?

Answer (score 66):

If you want to save the image and you know its URL you can do this:

```
try(InputStream in = new URL("http://example.com/image.jpg").openStream()){
    Files.copy(in, Paths.get("C:/File/To/Save/To/image.jpg"));
}
```

You will also need to handle the `IOException`s which may be thrown.

Comment: @carlosavoy Java, specifically Java 8, I think it will work in Java 7 also but I haven't tried it. idk about android.

Answer (score 12):

This works for me:

```
URL url = new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9c/Image-Porkeri_001.jpg");
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Image-Porkeri_001.jpg"));

for ( int i; (i = in.read()) != -1; ) {
    out.write(i);
}
in.close();
out.close();
```

Answer (score 12):

```
   // Do you want to download an image?
   // But are u denied access?
   // well here is the solution.

    public static void DownloadImage(String search, String path) {

    // This will get input data from the server
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    // This will read the data from the server;
    OutputStream outputStream = null;

    try {
        // This will open a socket from client to server
        URL url = new URL(search);

       // This user agent is for if the server wants real humans to visit
        String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36";

       // This socket type will allow to set user_agent
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

        // Setting the user agent
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        // Requesting input data from server
        inputStream = con.getInputStream();

        // Open local file writer
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(path);

        // Limiting byte written to file per loop
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

        // Increments file size
        int length;

        // Looping until server finishes
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            // Writing data
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(WebCrawler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }

     // closing used resources
     // The computer will not be able to use the image
     // This is a must

     outputStream.close();
     inputStream.close();
}
```

Comment: Could you add some comments to your answer?

Comment: What do you mean??

Comment: How do you know what buffer size to use? Here you used 2048 bytes but how do you know not to use 1028 or 4100?

Comment: How to determine the user agent string for the URL connection? Is there any standards set for this?

Comment: This is the key line of this answer where other answers failed to address. String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36";

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for a web crawler. You can use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org) to do this, [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links) is basic example

Answer (score 1):

The following code downloads an image from a direct link to the disk into the project directory. Also note that it uses [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

public class ImageDownloader
{
    public static void main(String[] arguments) throws IOException
    {
        downloadImage("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/73/Lion_waiting_in_Namibia.jpg",
                new File("").getAbsolutePath());
    }

    public static void downloadImage(String sourceUrl, String targetDirectory)
            throws MalformedURLException, IOException, FileNotFoundException
    {
        URL imageUrl = new URL(sourceUrl);
        try (InputStream imageReader = new BufferedInputStream(
                imageUrl.openStream());
                OutputStream imageWriter = new BufferedOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream(targetDirectory + File.separator
                                + FilenameUtils.getName(sourceUrl)));)
        {
            int readByte;

            while ((readByte = imageReader.read()) != -1)
            {
                imageWriter.write(readByte);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DownloadImageFromURL {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try  {
            final var url = new URL("https://53.fs1.hubspotusercontent-na1.net/hub/53/hubfs/image8-2.jpg?width=1190&height=800&name=image8-2.jpg");
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
            image.flush();
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("image_test.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```