# Java Spring Boot Restcontroller RequestMapping executed twice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot Application with a RestController and a method which will download and pass an image:

```
@RestController
public class PictureController {

    @RequestMapping("/picture/{id}")
    public HttpEntity<byte[]> getImage(@PathVariable String id)  {

        logger.info("Requested picture : >> " + id + " <<");

        // !! Execute code for downloading  !! 

        // Create Headers...

        // return HttpEntity<byte[]>
    }
}
```

In the logfiles I can read that the method is executed  **twice** and I don't know why.

If I remove the code for downloading it gets executed just **once** as expected.

Is it because it takes a second to download it?

The code for downloading is...

```
        byte[] response;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(....);

            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int n = 0;
            while (-1 != (n = in.read(buf))) {
                out.write(buf, 0, n);
            }
            out.close();
            in.close();
            response = out.toByteArray();
```

I also tried several solutions like...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/picture2/{id}", headers = "Accept=image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, image/gif") 
public @ResponseBody byte[] getArticleImage2(@PathVariable String id) {
```

I thought maybe a problem with HttpEntity but it's the same behaviour. Works as expected without code for downloading but with downloading an image it gets executed **twice**.

This is a serious performance issue of my application... :(

What is the problem here?

Comment: Any chance your "code for downloading" is hitting the same URL again, directly or indirectly?

Comment: I've checked it again and again and also with an network analyzer tool, so I can say: no it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem depends on the Browser which is used to test the RestController.
I'am using Firefox... and Firefox tend to get some html around an image. But the method doesn't return html and so Firefox is starting another request... also for looking for a favicon.

Internet Explorer e.g. doesn't care about it and the method is only executed once as expected!

So my problem is not a real problem because later my image delivered by the RestController will be embedded in a website which has html and a favicon.

Comment: He's right. I think this is an issue with Chrome. It's just a weird quirk I guess. I tried firefox and I only see the request once as expected. You should be fine if you make your requests using CURL, Postman or via Ajax once you're developing the front end calls.