# Servlet not writing file

Tags: java, servlets

I am uploading an image from `c:\illuxplain` on an android device. I have successfully uploaded the image but when I open it, it does not display.

Image size is non-zero in storage space and it displays extension `.png`. Why isn't the picture displaying? Is this right way to write file to storage space?

[image: Windows Photo Viewer can't open this picture...]

This is my **servlet code**

```
for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
    String fileName = extractFileName(part);
    File file = new File(fileSaveDir, fileName);
    InputStream input = part.getInputStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len = input.read();

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    while (len!=-1) {
        out.write(buffer,0,len);
        len = input.read(buffer);
    }
    out.close();
    input.close();
}
```

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882005/how-to-download-image-from-any-web-page-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong `read` method in the following line:

```
int len = input.read();
```

This should be:

```
int len = input.read(buffer);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate :)

Comment: Is it is good way to write to storage space? (Code I have post)

Comment: Usually one writes the loop as shown in sunrise76's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sample code:

```
byte data[] = new byte[1024];
long total = 0;
int count;


while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
         total += count;
         output.write(data, 0, count);
}

output.flush();
output.close();
```

Comment: Also consider making your `data` buffer much bigger - at least 10k.