# Saving Gravatar images to the database

Tags: java, image, gravatar

I want to use [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/) but I don't want to [publish users MD5 hashes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21117/is-using-gravatar-a-security-risk) of their e-mail addresses. And there is [more potential problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44717/is-gravatar-a-privacy-risk). So I decided to download them and store them in my database.
But I have a problem with such a simple task as my profile picture ([Earlybird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/channel/)) looks bad after downloading:

[image]

This is the code I used.

```
try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
    final URL url = new URL("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" + account.getGravatarHash() + "?d=identicon");
    final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", baos);
    pic = baos.toByteArray();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Value in `pic` is then directly stored to the database. Other pictures in my database are stored fine so problem must be in these lines.

EDIT:
I just partially fix the problem by changing `"jpg"` for a `"png"` even thought [Gravatar tutorial](https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/) is mentioning `"jpg"`. Also I don't want to specify image format (unless all Gravatars are `png`). Can I avoid that? I want just save the bytes I get.

Comment: Unit tests save the world. Test your pic byte[] against the same picture loaded from the local file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882005/how-to-download-image-from-any-web-page-in-java) with working solution:

```
try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()){
    final URL url = new URL("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" + account.getGravatarHash() + "?d=identicon");
    InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int n;
    while (-1 != (n = inputStream.read(buffer))) {
        baos.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }
    inputStream.close();
    pic = baos.toByteArray();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Looks like this works with `png` and `jpg` Gravatars.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers in most cases work with raw bytes. However it is highly appreciated to send "Content-Type: image/..." header for each image.

When you save bytes in DB you also have to

1. either save image **content type**, provided by Gravatar for this image or
2. convert image into your **default format**, so you can to hardcode content type for all images from your DB

To get headers, provided by Gravatar, you can use [Apache HTTP Client](https://hc.apache.org/).

To convert image into your preferred format, you can use ImageIO.

Comment: You can get content type even after it's stored in database, you can identify file format. A least for images. But looks like it works for Chrome and Firefox even when you don't specify content type in response or even give wrong one like `"image/jpeg"` for `png`.

Comment: Yes, clever browsers identifies image format themselves, without content-type hint from server. But your problem raises just from here - stupid browsers relays on this header