# Make Java use an input tag

Tags: java

I have this tag in one website I found

```html
<input type="button" value="Save Result As PNG">
```

When I click on it, it downloads an image automatically.
I´m trying to create a code that can make java "click" or perform the input action, so I can get all the images I want, but I don´t know where to start, or how to do it.

I also tried to download the image alone using this code

link:[how to download image from any web page in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882005/how-to-download-image-from-any-web-page-in-java)

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/image_to_read.jpg");
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int n = 0;
while (-1!=(n=in.read(buf)))
{
   out.write(buf, 0, n);
}
out.close();
in.close();
byte[] response = out.toByteArray();
```

but it didn´t work as well.

The site I´m trying to download the files is:
https://sanderfrenken.github.io/Universal-LPC-Spritesheet-Character-Generator/

Thank you very much!

Comment: "As you can see it saves one image into the download folder automatically"... what? I'm not seeing anything like that. I'm seeing an input button with a text "Save Result As PNG".

Comment: I´m  sorry, I changed

Comment: What do you mean by "but it didn't work as well" also, you write everything to ByteArrayOutputStream, but you never save those bytes to a file.

Comment: The page uses JavaScript to detect and handle a click on the button (jquery click), so a simple HTTP request with clothing parameters will not do.